# Error installing OASYS1-ShadowOui "No module named 'numpy.distutils'"discontinued

Tags: numpy

I am trying to install module 'OASYS1-ShadowOui', but i am facing an error

```
─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\sonuv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bjjm2wr_\shadow3_0bd69d6c577f4eccaa0a2dec9ad00d4c\setup.py", line 109, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.command.build_clib import build_clib
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
      [end of output]
```

numpy version numpy==1.26.3

Have tried to install an earlier version of NumPy but faced an error there, too. Using the latest version of Python and ShadowOui.

Comment: Setuptools already installed

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?